# _reactNativeGeocoding.default.setApiKey is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-api, geocoding

I'm trying to get the coordinates of a given address in React Native. I have tried the following:

```
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoding';
```

```
    Geocoder.setApiKey("AIz...ZI");
    Geocoder.from("London Eye")
        .then(json => {
            var location = json.results[0].geometry.location;
            console.log(location);
        })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error));
```

I have put the "..." in the API just to hide the entire key.

When I call the method in which this code is in, I get the error:

```
_reactNativeGeocoding.default.setApiKey is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the api key you need to call 'init' method instead of setApiKey

```
   Geocoder.init('AIz...ZI');
```